# Update Department id in an employee table from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1 using a single statement?

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query that updates the Department id in the employee table from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1 using a single statement.

Comment: This isn't making a lot of sense. You should edit your questions, and answers, before submitting them.

Answer (score 4):

Then go for it:

```
UPDATE employee SET departmentid = CASE departmentid WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 2 THEN 1 END
```

If there are other department IDs, put an `ELSE departmentid` in before the end, or a where clause for `departmentid in (1,2)`